# Google Client: Refreshing RefreshToken gives "invalid_grant" error

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

currently I have a problem with some accessTokens. I am using YouTube Data API and YouTube Analytics API to get some data from YouTube Channels.

For authentication I set the "state" to "offline" and "approvalPrompt" to force. So I get a refresh Token with the authentication. To refresh an access Token with refresh Token, I use the following code:

```
$client->setAccessToken("ACCESSTOKEN");

if( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() ) {
  $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
}
```

After that, I do some request to Google API. But when I execute a request, Google returns the following error:

> exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the
>   OAuth2 token, message: '{   "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/library/google-api-php/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:345
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/library/google-api-php/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(269):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
>   1 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/library/google-api-php/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(243):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/oiq78SCfplnl-...')
>   2 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/library/google-api-php/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(171):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_Http_Request))
>   3 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/library/google-api-php/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php(1694):
>   Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
>   4 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/app/tasks/CronjobTask.php(51): Google_Service_YouTube_Channels_Resource->listChannels('snippet,brandin...', Array)

Does anybody know, what the problem is? I also updated the server time, because I read that Google could have a problem with it. But this doesn't fix the problem.

Hint: This only happens to some accessTokens. I have several access Tokens where this code works fine. Yet there are other access Token where this code doesn't work, an I get the error above. **Could it be that the person revoked access for my app? Could this be a reason for this error message?**

Comment: what happens if you try again with the same refreshtoken?

Comment: As I see, the refreshToken never expired. If accessToken expired, and I get a new one with "$client->refreshToken($refresh_token)" there is still the same refreshToken inside the accessToken object. So I am using the same refreshToken everytime.

Comment: Are you checking that the refreshToken is valid when you try to refresh the access token? According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration), it's possible the refreshToken can become invalid if the user revokes access for the app, doesn't use the token for 6 months, or if the user account has exceeded the token limit (currently 25), in which case the older ones will become invalid so that the newer ones can be used.

Comment: what @not_a_bot said and add they can also remove your access.   My question once you have gotten this message will that refresh token work again if you try it later? or will it always return that error in which case its not valid you need to request a new one